# "Plugin blocked" even if whitelisting site for Flash

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, flash

I have gone through every single item on Google's [Use or fix Flash audio & video](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?visit_id=1-636449477872405743-3949815844&p=ib_blocked_plugin&rd=3)
 page, yet the address bar still displays a "Plugin blocked" text on every page load.

I then *have to* press the text and select "Run all plugins this time", in order to be able to run [the Flash content](https://listen.tidal.com).

I am a bit at a loss of what to fix this nuisance, which I see every time I  use [Tidal](https://listen.tidal.com) on Linux, as it doesn't have a desktop app.

Is there a fix for this, except for ticking "Run all flash content" on all sites?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing these steps in order, then restart Chrome and see if it works.

1. In chrome://plugins, check "Always allowed to run" for Adobe Flash Player
2. Open the menu and go to Settings -> Show advanced settings -> Privacy -> Content Settings -> Flash -> Manage Exceptions and add "https://listen.tidal.com/" and select "Allow" under Behavior.
3. In chrome://flags, enable "Run all Flash content when Flash setting is set to "allow""

Comment: As said, I already tested all of the things on the official Google Page. 
1. `chrome://plugins/` hasn't worked since Chrome 57 (disabled).
2. Already enabled.
3. There is no such option in the latest Chrome. Actually no flags relating to Flash at all.